# Why am I getting "specified cast not valid" here?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a column `MyColumn` of type `INT` and I am retrieving some rows with that column

```
string selectQuery = $@" SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
                         WHERE [Id] IN ('{testid_1}','{testid_2}','{testid_3}')
                         ORDER BY [MyColumn]";

var vals = mydb.ExecuteQuery<int?>(selectQuery).ToList();
```

where `db` is of type `DataContext`.

Any idea why this is giving me an invalid cast exception?

Comment: Ahhhh!  I spied Jon Skeet!

Comment: You say that your field is Not null, but you are casting it to nullable int. Why?

Comment: Still. is your field nullable or not? (I saw that you removed not null from text)

Comment: @AshkanSirous It is nullable

Comment: `{testid_1}...{testid_3}` are of type `varchar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of the below line where it's trying to cast `VARCHAR` type to `INT`

```
WHERE [Id] IN ('{testid_1}','{testid_2}','{testid_3}')
```